# Akka: Should I use parallelStream or executors in an actor

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I am new to Akka actor model. As I understand, akka provides abstraction over parallelism and concurrency. Having said that, I don't feel it's right to have concurrency via parallelStream or executor framework in an actor itself, wanted to know if this is an anti-pattern. Also, does that mean all code in an actor would be sequential always ?

Comment: If you do not consider the `Future` in an actor, yes, all code in an actor is sequential as `Future` will run another thread. If you mean actor as `class MyActor extends Actor` not the instance of it, then answer maybe no, as we can specify nr-of-instances for actor to allow run in more thread. Anyway, the topic is so big...

Comment: [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/xOFJ0eQJOS4) sounds relevant, and the answer seems to be "likely not". [This illustration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-parallelism.html) seems relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the parallel streams of Java itself, then "likely not". Especially as most of the "get results" operations on those are blocking, so you'd be forced to block in the Actor, which indeed is an anti-pattern (read here about it: [blocking needs careful management](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/dispatchers.html#blocking-needs-careful-management)).

You can however use [Akka Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/stream/index.html?language=java) inside Actors more freely, this is because all of their operations offload the work to a separate dispatcher, so it won't block the Actor. They're also more configurable and offer [connectors to various tech](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/), and [integrate well Actors themselves](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-integrations.html#integrating-with-actors).